# Have computed binding fire when array sub property changes?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.*

I am trying to refine the behavior of my computed binding with a array. I had `<div hidden$="[[getState(uploadState.*)]]">FOO</div>` but it was firing off to often.

I refined it to `uploadState.value`:

```
  <template is="dom-repeat"
    initial-count="1"
    index-as="index"
    items="{{uploadState}}">

    <div hidden$="[[getState(uploadState.value)]]">FOO</div>
```

With:

```
    uploadState: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() {
        var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(5));
        var newArray = arr.map(()=> {
          return {
            value: false,
            main: false,
            edited: false,
            loading: false
          };
        });
        return newArray;
      },
      notify: true
    },

  attached: function() {
    setTimeout(()=>  this.set(`uploadState.0.value`, true), 1000)
  }
```

but it does not fire off at all. How can I make it fire in the computed binding when the `value` property changes?

Also, how can I use `this.get()` to get the value  when it changes? I tried `var uploaded = this.get(['uploadState.value', 0])` in the computed binding `getState` but it just shows undefined(when it used to fire with the .*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your usage of the binding `uploadState.value` is it doesn't exist. You are making an array of `uploadState` that have a member with the property `value` which looks more like `uploadState.*.value` but you don't really want to change on all the changes of value, just the one in question so you can take advantage of the `item` binding of `dom-repeat` so that your code would come out like so:

```
<template is="dom-repeat"
  initial-count="1"
  index-as="index"
  items="{{uploadState}}">
    <div hidden$="[[item.value]]">FOO</div>
</template>
```

I might suggest you change up your naming convention and use `uploadStates` being it's an array and all, so that you can do:

```
<template is="dom-repeat"
  initial-count="1"
  index-as="index"
  items="{{uploadStates}}"
  as="uploadState">
    <div hidden$="[[uploadState.value]]">FOO</div>
</template>
```